# ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, node.js

Why isn't it working?
I want download txt and save in a database.

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th                                                                                                                               at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a/                                                                                                                               innego komunikatora. Z góry, wielkie dzięki. Temat będzie aktualizowany w m' at                                                                                                                                line 1

#### Code

```js
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');


var con = mysql.createConnection({
  password..
});


con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});


let x=1;

function downlad(){
    x++;
    request.get(`http://wklejto.pl/638151`, (err, response, body) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        const $=cheerio.load(
          body,
          { decodeEntities: false });

        const el = $('.de1').html();

        con.query("INSERT INTO `wklejki` (`ID`, `txt`) VALUES (NULL, '"+el+"');");

        console.log(el);
    });
}downlad();
```

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h73t4.png)

Comment: Are there `'` characters in the text you want to insert? If yes, that prematurely ends the string in your `VALUES`. By the way, the script is vulnerable to injection attacks, you should use prepared statements instead. mandatory [bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) link

Comment: Ty,my text have ' :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
con.query("INSERT INTO `wklejki` (`ID`, `txt`) VALUES (NULL, '"+el+"');");
```

with

```
con.query('INSERT INTO wklejki SET ?', {ID: null, txt: el}, function (error, results, fields) {
    //Whatever you want to do next.
});
```